# Stored procedure MERGE (INSERT OR UPDATE) and return ID issue

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

So I'm trying to learn how to use stored procedures and for the most part I somewhat understand how to use them except for this merge procedure.

What I'm trying to do is use the MERGE procedure to Insert if a row does not already exist and return the ID ELSE IF NOT EXISTS then just return the ID.

Here is currently what I have so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@FirstName nvarchar(50), 
@LastName nvarchar(50),
@id int = NULL OUTPUT
AS
MERGE Authors AS target
USING (SELECT @FirstName, @LastName) AS source (FirstName, LastName)
ON target.FirstName = source.FirstName AND target.LastName = source.LastName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
    (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (source.FirstName, source.LastName);
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Everything works fine as far as inputting the values/information into the database and finding an existing one but I'm not getting my ID value back correctly. Here is my method that uses it..

```
private static int storeAuthors(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            String commandText = "dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AmazonCrawler.Properties.Settings.database"].ToString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", firstName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lastName));
                    SqlParameter authorId = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    authorId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(authorId);

                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();

                    return Convert.ToInt32(authorId.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me fix this!

Thanks in advance.

---------EDIT------------

Updated the procedure to this yet I'm still receiving a null value in my code when i try to return the value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @id int OUTPUT
AS
MERGE Authors AS target
USING (SELECT @id, @FirstName, @LastName) AS source (id, FirstName, LastName)
ON target.FirstName = source.FirstName AND target.LastName = source.LastName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (source.FirstName, source.LastName);
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Edit reference 1
[image]

Edit reference 2

[image]

Edit reference 3

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @id int OUTPUT

AS
MERGE Authors AS target
USING (SELECT @id, @FirstName, @LastName) AS source (ID, FirstName, LastName)
ON target.FirstName = source.FirstName AND target.LastName = source.LastName
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET @id = target.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (source.FirstName, source.LastName);
    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT @id
```

Still receiving same error listed in reference 2. 
=( no solution yet.

here is my passed in values with a return of zero as an id
[image]

and here is my database

[image]

Edit reference 4

Tried changing my parameters when putting in the values to this as I thought perhaps closing it before getting the value was causing the problem but no luck

```
private static int storeAuthors(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            String commandText = "dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AmazonCrawler.Properties.Settings.database"].ToString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", firstName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lastName));
                    SqlParameter authorId = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    authorId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    command.Parameters.Add(authorId);

                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int value = Convert.ToInt32(authorId.Value);
                    connection.Close();

                    return value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the update case you're using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which seems to be a c&p error.

Comment: made the change yet still receiving a null value in the code when I try running it.

Comment: What change did you make? I did not suggest any.

Comment: Well, what did you expect with that change? You just deleted the UPDATE case. So in case of an UPDATE nothing happens.

Comment: Well I've tried so far using just   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
 SET @id = target.ID  But this gives me an incorrect syntax.

Comment: I have added additional pictures to reference 3 of my database and my code with the watch list displaying my values being sent to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UPDATE case, you aren't generating a new IDENTITY, you are just querying, so SCOPE_IDENTITY() won't return the right value. In the UPDATE case, SCOPE_IDENTITY() may appear to work, at first, but it is actually returning the value from the last INSERT in scope (I think), which could be the last execution of the stored proc.

I recommend using the OUTPUT clause. I tried to make something work with your approach, and with @usr's suggestion as well, but the only thing I could make work was to use the OUTPUT clause. See below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FirstName nvarchar(50), 
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @id int OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @MergeOutput table
   ( 
     ACTION VARCHAR(10),
     ID INT
   );

   MERGE Authors AS target
     USING (SELECT @id, @FirstName, @LastName) AS source (id, FirstName, LastName)
       ON target.FirstName = source.FirstName AND target.LastName = source.LastName
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (source.FirstName, source.LastName)
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
       SET @Id = target.Id
     OUTPUT $action, INSERTED.ID INTO @MergeOutput;

   SELECT @Id = Id FROM @MergeOutput

END
GO

DECLARE @id2 INT
exec dbo.authors_InsertOrUpdate 'Melvin', 'Smith', @id = @id2 OUTPUT
SELECT @id2
GO
```

I tried to make something work using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), and using SET @Id = target.Id as in @usr's answer but I kept getting the last inserted value returned, even for an update.

Comment: After making the changes you suggested I am now receiving a null value from code in authorID.Value

Comment: I'm not clear on your intent. The reason I recommended removing the "WHEN MATCHED" is because it was doing nothing, except attempting to update the primary key. You removed "WHEN NOT MATCHED" which is not what I suggested.

Comment: see the first edit picture. I did not remove "WHEN NOT MATCHED" it is still there.

Comment: My mistake. I looked at the 2nd picture and glanced over too fast to see the mouseover / tooltip obscuring.

Comment: I did but still nothing. see reference 3 for current stored procedure.

Comment: yea I'm still getting a null back =( I also tried changing my parameters the way I'm sending it to reference 4 but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54402/discussion-between-mrjoltcola-and-tyler-buchanan).

Comment: also I don't get a problem inserting. I've already got values in my database. It's when I try to update and get the id back.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO #o FROM sys.objects

DECLARE @id INT

MERGE #o AS target
USING (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#o') AS object_id) AS source (object_id)
ON target.object_id = source.object_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET @id = target.object_id;

SELECT @id
```

You can use columns of the `MERGE` query pretty freely. It is a very powerful statement.

Comment: @TylerBuchanan That must be some problem not visible in the code shown. I added a self-contained repro to this answer. It works.

Comment: I understand this is a frustrating problem as I would not be posting to this board otherwise. however I cannot mark this as an answer as this code does not work for me and I have listed the method that uses it and I am passing in the correct values yet I still do not receive the id back.

Comment: Also I don't get a problem inserting. I've already got values in my database. It's when I try to update and get the id back. So I'm assuming yours will work for you however its working on the insert and not the update which is where im having the problem.